# Fast sparse matrix multiplication w/o allocating a dense array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have an m x m sparse matrix `similarities` and a vector with m elements, `combined_scales`. I wish to multiply the ith column in `similarities` by `combined_scales[i]`. Here's my first attempt at this:

```
for i in range(m):
    scale = combined_scales[i]
    similarities[:, i] *= scale
```

This is semantically correct but was performing poorly, so I tried changing it to this:

```
# sparse.diags creates a diagonal matrix.
# docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html
similarities *= sparse.diags(combined_scales)
```

But I immediately got a `MemoryError` when running this line. Bizarrely, it seems that scipy is attempting to allocate a dense numpy array here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 108, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 466, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 100, in main
    magic.fit(df)
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\py\relativity\ml.py", line 127, in fit
    self._scale_similarities(X, net_similarities)
  File "C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\py\relativity\ml.py", line 148, in _scale_similarities
    similarities *= sparse.diags(combined_scales)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 440, in __mul__
    return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
  File "C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 503, in _mul_sparse_matrix
    data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
MemoryError
```

How do I prevent it from allocating a dense array here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're allocating a dense array? Run `similarities.count_nonzero()` and tell us what it returns.

Comment: Actually, the last line of the traceback suggest it is trying to allocate a sparse result, `nnz` standing for "number of non zeros".

Comment: What format is `similarities`?

Answer (score 2):

From `sparse.compressed`

```
class _cs_matrix    # common for csr and csc
    def _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other):
        M, K1 = self.shape
        K2, N = other.shape

        major_axis = self._swap((M,N))[0]
        other = self.__class__(other)  # convert to this format

        idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((self.indptr, self.indices,
                                     other.indptr, other.indices),
                                    maxval=M*N)
        indptr = np.empty(major_axis + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)

        fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_pass1')
        fn(M, N,
           np.asarray(self.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
           np.asarray(self.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
           np.asarray(other.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
           np.asarray(other.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
           indptr)

        nnz = indptr[-1]
        idx_dtype = get_index_dtype((self.indptr, self.indices,
                                     other.indptr, other.indices),
                                    maxval=nnz)
        indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
        indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
        data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))

        fn = getattr(_sparsetools, self.format + '_matmat_pass2')
        fn(M, N, np.asarray(self.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
           np.asarray(self.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
           self.data,
           np.asarray(other.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
           np.asarray(other.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
           other.data,
           indptr, indices, data)

        return self.__class__((data,indices,indptr),shape=(M,N))
```

`similarities` is a sparse csr matrix.  `other`, the `diag` matrix, has been converted to csr as well in

```
other = self.__class__(other)
```

`csr_matmat_pass1` (compiled code) is run with the indices from `self` and `other`, returning `nnz`, the number of nonzero terms in the output.

It then allocates the `indptr`, `indices` and `data` arrays that will hold the results from `csr_matmat_pass2`.  These are used to create the return matrix

```
self.__class__((data,indices,indptr),shape=(M,N))
```

The error occurs in creating the `data` array:

```
data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
```

The return result just has too many nonzero values for your memory.

What is `m`, and `similarities.nnz`?

Is there enough memory to do `similarities.copy()`?

While you are using `similarities *= ...`, it first has to do `similarities * other`.  The result will then replace `self`.  It does not attempt to do an in-place multiplication.

### inplace iteration by column

There have been a lot of questions about faster iteration by rows (or columns), seeking to do things like sorting or getting the largest row values.  Working directly with the `csr` attributes can speed this up considerably.  I think the idea applies here

Example:

```
In [275]: A = sparse.random(10,10,.2,'csc').astype(int)
In [276]: A.data[:] = np.arange(1,21)
In [277]: A.A
Out[277]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0, 16, 18],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 11, 14,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  9, 12,  0,  0, 17,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  7,  0,  0,  0, 15,  0, 19],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20]])
In [280]: B = sparse.diags(np.arange(1,11),dtype=int)
In [281]: B
Out[281]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
In [282]: (A*B).A
Out[282]: 
array([[  0,   0,  12,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   6,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   0,   0,   0,   0,  60,   0,   0, 144, 180],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  66,  98,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,  40,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,  45,  72,   0,   0, 153,   0],
       [  2,   0,   0,   0,   0,  78,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,  15,  28,   0,   0,   0, 120,   0, 190],
       [  0,   0,  18,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 200]], dtype=int64)
```

Inplace iteration on columns:

```
In [283]: A1=A.copy()
In [284]: for i,j,v in zip(A1.indptr[:-1],A1.indptr[1:],np.arange(1,11)):
     ...:     A1.data[i:j] *= v
     ...:     
In [285]: A1.A
Out[285]: 
array([[  0,   0,  12,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   6,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  1,   0,   0,   0,   0,  60,   0,   0, 144, 180],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  66,  98,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,  40,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,  45,  72,   0,   0, 153,   0],
       [  2,   0,   0,   0,   0,  78,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,  15,  28,   0,   0,   0, 120,   0, 190],
       [  0,   0,  18,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 200]])
```

Time comparisons:

```
In [287]: %%timeit A1=A.copy()
     ...: A1 *= B
     ...: 
375 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [288]: %%timeit A1 = A.copy()
     ...: for i,j,v in zip(A1.indptr[:-1],A1.indptr[1:],np.arange(1,11)):
     ...:     A1.data[i:j] *= v
     ...:     
79.9 µs ± 1.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```